# Ember-data hasMany association not working

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I have a couple models set up like follows:

```
WT.WorkoutPlan = DS.Model.extend({
   workouts: DS.hasMany('planWorkout'),
   name: DS.attr()
});

WT.PlanWorkout = DS.Model.extend({});
```

When I attempt to load the model with the following JSON, the workout is loaded fine as evidenced by `plan.get('name');` returning the name correction, but `plan.get('workouts')` always has 0 members.  Anyone know why the association isn't loading?

Here's the JSON:

```
{
     "planWorkouts": [
         {
            "id": 991,
            "name": "Lower Body"
         }
     ],
     "workoutPlan": {
         "id": 343,
         "name": "male-20to39-fat-loss",
         "planWorkouts": [991]
     }
}
```

I'm using ember-data 1.0beta3

Comment: can you try using "plan-workouts" as key?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This

```
"workoutPlan": {
     "id": 343,
     "name": "male-20to39-fat-loss",
     "planWorkouts": [991]
 }
```

should be

```
"workoutPlan": {
     "id": 343,
     "name": "male-20to39-fat-loss",
     "workouts": [991]
 }
```

aka the key should be workouts, not planWorkouts in  your json

Comment: This seemed to do it for me.  Still not seeing workouts in my template, but the Ember inspector is showing the association correctly.

Comment: Anyone reading this and using the fixture adapter, you should make your Ids Strings. Read this: http://www.vinay.io/static/blog/2013/12_17.html

Comment: You should submit a PR for string coercion in the fixture adapter.

Answer (score 0):

workoutPlan should containt workout_ids, also you can side-load that workouts by adding "workouts" to the hash, remember: workouts live outside workoutPlan root hash.

```
{
    "workoutPlan": {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "male-20to39-fat-loss"
    "workout_ids": [ 1 ]
  },

  "workouts": [
    { "id": 1, "body": "what a dumb post" }
  ]
}
```

Comment: I was setting up the sideloaded models correctly, but my I had `planWorkouts` instead of `workouts` for the key in the parent model, which matched the Model name, not the hasmany attribute name.

Comment: Additionally qrooel, for your own kicks and giggles, that format has changed in 1.0.  You no longer do key_ids, See https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/master/TRANSITION.md